# PHP: Read JSON file with multiple objects in array and split by objects

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a file with content similar to this:

```
[{"color":1,"blocks":[[{"id":64}]]},{"color":1,"blocks":[[{"id":64},{"id":64}],[{"id":1}]]},{"color":2,"blocks":[[{"id":64},{"id":64}],[{"id":1}]]}]
```

For example the file above has 3 objects with elements: color and blocks.
I am searching for an easy way with PHP to output only one object of the file. (remove outer `[]`-brackets and split first level `{}`-brackets into different elements of an array or different strings or something)

The result should be for object1

```
{"color":1,"blocks":[[{"id":64}]]}
```

or for object2

```
{"color":1,"blocks":[[{"id":64},{"id":64}],[{"id":1}]]}
```

How to say PHP take the string and split it for each `{"color"` it can find into parts or by using the first level `{}`-brackets?

at the moment I am using `$config=json_decode($file,true);` and my code is like
`echo '{"color":'.$config[2]["color"].'"blocks"` ... but thats crazy the object has too many elements 
i need a way like `echo $config[2]` that outputs `{"color":2,"blocks":[[{"id":64},{"id":64}],[{"id":1}]]}`

I tried to read the file as string and use explode but `"},"` or `"color"` as delimiter does not work and I can't find a valid delimiter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decode then encode:

```
$str = '[{"color":1,"blocks":[[{"id":64}]]},{"color":1,"blocks":[[{"id":64},{"id":64}],[{"id":1}]]},{"color":2,"blocks":[[{"id":64},{"id":64}],[{"id":1}]]}]';
$config = json_decode($str, true);
$json = json_encode($config[2]);
print $json;
```

This will print what you want.

Answer (score 3):

You're going about it wrong. You don't output json, you extract the sub-array/object and then re-encode that. e.g.

```
$foo = json_decode($your_json);
$temp = $foo['bar'][1]['baz']; // deep sub-data
echo json_encode($temp);
```

No substring operations/mangling required. Just decode, extract, re-encode extracted portion.